# Playing audio file with Python

Tags: python, audio, mp3

I've seen most of the questions on this topic but almost all of them are outdated. (This is not a dupe)

**My requirement is a preferably light weight library for simply playing audio files such as mp3,etc from Python (2.7)**

These are the libraries that I've so far looked into and I'm listing what are the things that are stopping me from using each of them:

- [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/): it was last updated in Feb, 2006
- [Mp3Play](http://code.google.com/p/mp3play/): supports only XP and was last updated in 2008.

I've also tried [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) but even this doesn't look good.
Also heard that wx has support for mp3 and I'm trying it. Any comments about the same?

Which reliable lightweight library do others use these days?

PS: please post one library only per answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what your issue is with [`pyglet`](http://www.pyglet.org/). Playing an mp3 using that couldn't be simpler:

```
import pyglet
sound = pyglet.media.load('mysound.mp3', streaming=False)
sound.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

pyglet is well-maintained, cross-platform, and very small for a multimedia library.

Comment: Actually I installed it and when I write a program importing pyglet it's not detecting the library, perhaps the reason could be that pyglet is supported for Python till 2.6? When I install it, in requirements it says: 
`pyglet requires either:
Python 2.4 with ctypes installed
Python 2.5 or Python 2.6`

Comment: pyglet supports Python 2.7, but apparently there's a bug in the installer http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/issues/detail?id=488, try installing from source

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks. will try installing from source, but it's the problem you see, would u still call it well maintained! :)

Comment: @Atul my experience with a lot of libraries (especially pure Python libraries where it's easy to install from source) maintaining a Windows installer isn't a top priority. This could also have been fixed but hasn't made it into a stable release yet.

Comment: @Atul I've used PyAudiere recently, but again, it's not well maintained. Pyglet looks to be a reasonable option, if you can excuse the current bug in the windows installer.

Comment: @Rafe I installed it from source but apparently Avbin is also needed for mp3 playback, as written [here](http://www.pyglet.org/download.html) I downloaded Avbin (which is a dll) now where do I paste this dll?

Comment: @Atul just a guess, but try "C:\Python27\libs", which is where I believe Python keeps its DLLs on Windows.

Comment: @Rafe Thanks but think even that's not working out, not getting any error msg or something but just the song wouldn't play even if I paste the dll there... Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: @Rafe I got it, I've edited your answer to add a missing statement in the code. Thanks, can play the music now! ♫ ♫ ♫

Comment: @Rafe: perhaps you or some moderator discarded my edit to the answer without stating any reason!!
Anyways, we also need to add `pyglet.app.run()` after `sound.play()` to play the sound. I added the line in my code, and it worked. :)

Comment: @Rafe ahh, Thanks! must have been some mod, no probs :)

Comment: [mp3 @ 0x1b19e40] max_analyze_duration reached

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but anyway...

Try [just_playback](https://github.com/cheofusi/just_playback). It's a wrapper around miniaudio that can read multiple file formats including mp3 and provides playback control functionality like pausing, resuming, seeking and setting the playback volume.